# How change class for all elements after and before this element?

Tags: jquery

Good day.

I have code html:

```
<span class="empty-star level" style="cursor:pointer" id="1"></span>
<span class="empty-star level" style="cursor:pointer" id="2"></span>
<span class="empty-star level" style="cursor:pointer" id="3"></span>
<span class="empty-star level" style="cursor:pointer" id="4"></span>
<span class="empty-star level" style="cursor:pointer" id="5"></span>
```

I would like that when i click on element with class `level` all elements before him, change class with `empty-class` to `good-class` and all elements after him change class with `good-class` to `empty-class`.

Tell me please how make this?

Comment: Do you mean `empty-class`/`good-class` or `empty-star`/`good-star`? Can you also post your attempts at solving this problem?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.prevAll()` and `nextAll()` for this purpose:

```
$('.level').on('click', function() {
    $(this)
      .prevAll('.empty-class')
        .toggleClass('empty-class good-class') // remove empty, add good
        .end()
      .nextAll('.good-class')
        .toggleClass('good-class empty-class'); // remove good, add empty
});
```

Comment: I didn't know they exists, I wanted to post answer with `while(elem = elem.prev())`

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.level').on('click', function() {
    $(this).prevAll('.empty-class').removeClass('empty-class').
        addClass('good-class');
    $(this).nextAll('.good-class').removeClass('good-class').
        addClass('empty-class');
});
```

Comment: `prev('.level')` and `next('.level')`

Comment: What do you mean? It's not stated in your original question

Comment: in your code need change `.prevAll('.empty-class')` on `.prevAll('.level')` and `.nextAll('.good-class')` on `.nextAll('.level')`.
but thanks for help and answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.prev()` and `.next()` jQuery functions!

http://api.jquery.com/prev/

http://api.jquery.com/next/

And you can use `.addClass()` and  `.removeClass()`

http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/

//Edit:

If you want to asign classes to more then one prev or next element you can use `.prevAll()` / `.nextAll()` or `.prevUntil()` / `.nextUntil()`

http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/

http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/

http://api.jquery.com/prevUntil/

http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/

Comment: `prev()` and `next()` only match the *immediately* previous or next elements. I don't think they would solve the questioner's problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$(".level").click(function() {
    var thisId = $(this).attr("id");
    $.each($(".level"), function(index) {
        if(this.id < thisId) {
            $(this).removeClass("empty-class");
            $(this).addClass("good-class");
        }
        else if(this.id > thisId) {
            $(this).removeClass("good-class");
            $(this).addClass("empty-class");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".level").click(function()
{
    $(this).prevAll().removeClass("empty-class").addClass("good-class");
    $(this).nextAll().removeClass("good-class").addClass("empty-class");
});
```